# jquery/javascript image slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple (at least i thought it was) images slide for my website.
I am very new to jquery and javascript so my script is probably a bit dodgy. Here's the code:

$(function() {

```
var images = ["images/animal_full_2.jpg","images/church_full_1.jpg", "images/city_full_2.jpg", "images/faith_full_1.jpg", "images/flower_full_2.jpg", "images/gloom_full_2.jpg"];

function swapImages()
    {

        images=0;
        $("#"+images).fadeOut(2000,function(){
            (this).attr('src',++images).fadeIn(2000,function(){
                setTimeout(swapImages(),2000)
            });


        });

    }
```

});

now, what I was trying to achieve was a slideshow so that the images in the array change at a regular interval and they they start again, but this is what happens as you can see (please note that by including the URL I am not trying to promote my site, but to simply show how the script isn't working):
http://antobbo.webspace.virginmedia.com/photogallery/testscript/home.htm
The images are all displayed on the home page.
Does anybody have any suggestion as to how to get it working?
thanks a lot

Comment: There are several jquery plugins which offer this functionality. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Writing it himself is a good way to learn.

Comment: depends how mutch time you have, if you have the time i vote for learning it yourself too, but in many cases you come with this question when time is pressing, clients breathing down your neck, it's in those times i praise those who did it before me :)

Comment: There's a number of different ways to go about doing this, but the first thing you want to clarify is the expected behavior. Is just one image available and it's fading out while another one is fading in? Also, why are you setting your images array variable to zero inside your function? Did you mean to use a different variable?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with what you have so far, so maybe it will be easier for you to just see a working example.  This should work with your document:

```
$(function() {
    var imgs = $('.home_page_pic img').hide(), index = 0;

    imgs.eq(index).show();

    function swapImages() {
      imgs.eq(index).fadeOut(2000, function(){

        index++;
        if (index == imgs.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
        imgs.eq(index).fadeIn(2000, swapImages);
      });
    }

    swapImages();
});
```

Comment: thanks for that!there are few things that are not clear: 1)when you say “imgs.length”, that has value 5. WHy is that? I thought length returns the number of characthers in a string how does it manage to return 5 here?2)in this line imgs.eq(index).fadeIn(2000, swapImages); swapImages is a call back function. Why do we need it?From what I read call back functions are there to prevent another function to run before the animation.So why r you using it. 3)at the end of the script you call again swapImages():why do you do that?

Comment: jack sorry just noticed something. The script doesn't work the first time it runs the pictures appear below the main picture. The subsequent runs are instead ok, have a look: http://antobbo.webspace.virginmedia.com/photogallery/home.htm

Comment: This worked perfectly with the original page you posted.  I opened a JS console on your site and tested it.

Comment: hi jack, that's odd because I am still having the problem, although it is just in chrome, on page refresh. it seems to have sth to do with the display property of the first image which, even when hidden remains display:inline; instead of display:none; as a consequence of the .hide() method. I used the console in opera and firefox and it works as it should, it is just chrome for whathever reason. It's like .hide() isn't doing what it is supposed to do in chrome